# Python проблема с циклом while

Tags: python, while

Программа по переводу из 10-ой системы счисления в 5-ти и 7-меричную.

```
n = int(input())
rez = []
rez2= []
n2 = n
n2 = int(n2)
while n > 1:
    o = n % 5
    o = int(o)
    n = n / 5
    rez.append(o)
print(rez)
while n2 > 1:
    o1 = n2 % 7
    o1 = int(o1)
    n2 = n2 / 7
    rez.append(o1)
print(rez2)
```

второй цикл просто не работает. Объясните, почему не работает.

Comment: Во втором цикле вы значения добавляете в список rez вместо rez2.

Comment: @Интик для целых чисел такое присваивание вполне нормально. Не понятно правда зачем там целое число еще раз к целому типу приводится.

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [mre] до публикации вопроса.

Comment: Сначала `n2` присваивается ссылка на `n`, но после присваивания `n = n / 5` переменная `n` начинает указывать на другой объект, а в `n2` остаётся первоначальное значение `n`.

Answer (score 4):

Как было уже сказано в комментариях вы добавляли значения в rez вместо rez2. Так же данные массивы необходимо развернуть для правильного результата.

Вот рабочий код:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    rez = []
    rez2 = []
    n2 = n
    n2 = int(n2)
    while n > 1:
        o = n % 5
        o = int(o)
        n = n / 5
        rez.append(o)
    print(rez[::-1])
    while n2 > 1:
        o1 = n2 % 7
        o1 = int(o1)
        n2 = n2 / 7
        rez2.append(o1)
    print(rez2[::-1])
```